# Sci-kit Learn Beta Score interpretation: How to use the 'beta' and 'average' param correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, unbalanced-classes, precision-recall

I am building a model for a class imbalance problem, which I want to be as recall oriented as possible for the minority class. The model I have built uses class weights to penalize the majority class (almost heavily). I came across Sci-kit learn's fbeta_score metric. 
From it's official documentation: "fbeta_score is the harmonic mean of precision and recall". I want to use it to evaluate the model by giving complete weight to recall.

However, I am unable to understand how to set the 'beta' and the use of the 'average' parameter ('micro', 'macro' or 'weighted'). How and when am I supposed to use it?

Comment: Do you have a multi-class problem (not binary)? That option only applies in that case

Comment: Yes, there are 5 classes.